# Hora fica adiantada em programa C

Tags: c, windows, time

Tenho uma aplicação em C, acabei ela porém estou com um problema com a hora. Exemplo: eu estou gravando tudo o que é feito com data e hora só que a hora fica adiantada. Quando eu faço uma operação às 12:54 a hora apresentada é 15:54:16, segue abaixo o código:

> Obs: a hora do computador esta correta.

```
SYSTEMTIME str_t;
GetSystemTime(&str_t);
```

Depois disso acesso as informações, e o `str_t` no *debug* já esta com a hora errada.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação desta função](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtime?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) o retorno é feito em horário [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (que no fundo é o horário GMT) e o seu computador provavelmente está em horário de Brasília que é três horas atrasada. Então você está pegando a hora corretamente, só está esquecendo que precisa tratá-la adequadamente para o que deseja, ou seja, aplicar o fuso horário.

Por outro lado se você quer pegar o horário local use a função correta, no caso a [`GetLocalTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getlocaltime?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Entendi, como eu faria esse tratamento em .c?

Comment: Editado para indicar a solução correta.

Comment: Perfeito, era isso que queria! Muito simples rsss. Vou marcar como correta, mais tenho que esperar 2 min...